# How to fix jQuery and CSS problems?

Tags: jquery, css

My Page:

[image: Button]

from the left to right is meant for; *Normal*, *On Hover* and *Active*. I am using a jQuery drop down feature, whereas I would like the normal image to show when the mouse is not over or it is active, the on hover image to show when you hover over and the active image to show when you click and the drop down appears.

I also need the caret to be 9px from the top and 4px from the left and if possible for it not to be selectable.

My page can be [found here](https://tornhq.com/WorkingOn/Account/Management/PageBuilder/untitled.html)

**EDIT:**
A [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YVnfs/) has just been made.

```
<div id="Font-Type">
    <div class="dropdown">
        Arial <a href="#Font-Type" class="dropdown-toggle">▼</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="Arial">Arial</li>
            <li>Monospace</li>
            <li>Cursive</li>
            <li>Fantasy</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please not that I have chosen to do the drop down like this for the font-type drop down to display a preview of the font, of which is temporary not working but I know the problem and am trying to sort out this one first, as seen above.

**Edit for David Fregoli**

```
#Font-Size {
    width:14px;
    height:22px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:8px;
}
#Font-Size.img {
    background:url(../../../Images/TextEditor/buttons.png) no-repeat;
    background-position:0 0;
}
#Font-Size.img:hover {
    background:url(../../../Images/TextEditor/buttons.png) no-repeat;
    background-position:0 14;
}
```

The following CSS shows nothing, even if I specify 'top left' for example.

**Update:**
See the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YVnfs/2/) thanks to [David Fregoli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1680422/david-fregoli). All that is left to be answered now is how to get the caret to be 9px from the top and 4px from the left and the active to stay active whilst the drop down is open.

Comment: I suggest to make a plunkr / jsfiddle version of this, so that others can improve it and post answers to your question in an easier way. :)

Comment: [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it/126000#126000)

Comment: Sorry, I have now made a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 3):

You only need CSS pseudo selectors

```
a.img {
   background-image: //img1
}
a.img:hover {
   background-image: //img2
}
a.img:active {
   background-image: //img3
}
```

**edit** since you seem to have a single sprite instead of setting background-image you need to set the background-position property

Comment: This image is not a link, so therefore the a feature will not work. I have now included a JSFiddle into the question. Thanks

Comment: just change the `div` to `a`. setting its css `display: block` will make it behave like a `div`

Comment: Thank you, the initial background and hover images show correctly. Now to just work out how to move the caret 9px from the top and 4px from the left and make the active class show whilst the drop down is open.